# Accessing Parameters and Variables Made in a Function Outside of it (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time


def classBase(class_name, class_health, class_damage, class_hit_chance):
    print("You are a " + class_name + "!")

def enemyBase(enemy_name, enemy_health, enemy_damage, enemy_hit_chance, enemy_alive):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Out of nowhere, a " + enemy_name + " appears!")
    enemy_total_health = enemy_health



print("Welcome to Blades of Goblonia!")
user_name = input("What is your name?")
type(user_name)
print("Hello, " + user_name + "!")
user_class_choice = input("""What class would you like to be?
A) Warrior
B) Hunter
C) Wizard""")
if user_class_choice == "A" :
    user_class = classBase("Warrior", 50, 7, 95)
elif user_class_choice == "B" :
    user_class = classBase("Hunter", 40, 10, 85)
elif user_class_choice == "C" :
    user_class = classBase("Wizard", 35, 12, 80)

enemyBase("Goblin", 30, 10 , 60, True)

time.sleep(1)

user_action_choice = input("""Would you like to
    A) Hit
    B) Run
    C) Heal""")

if user_action_choice == "A" :
    print("Hit")
elif user_action_choice == "B" :
    print("Run")
elif user_action_choice == "C" :
    print("Heal")
```

In my game code, I'm trying to access and alter the health of enemyBase as it changes when I re-create it. To create a damage, effect, I need to change the value of enemy_total_health, but I can not reference the variable. How would I write my code to be able to access the local variables and parameters? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose you should make `Enemy` a class and goblin an instance of the `Enemy` class in order to keep track of all the attributes of your enemy as an object:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage, hit_chance, alive):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.total_health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.hit_chance = hit_chance
        self.alive = alive
        print("Out of nowhere, a " + name + " appears!")

goblin = Enemy("Goblin", 30, 10, 60, True)
print('%s has a total health of %d' % (goblin.name, goblin.total_health))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll convert my other functions in to classes too

Answer (score 0):

The main answer to what you're asking:

- Functions can't be used in the way that you're trying to use them. You want a class.

Other tips:

- Use a dictionary to map the class name to specific stats
- Create a `get_choice` function for re-usability when needing user input of "a", "b", "c", etc.
- Use a `main()` function to limit the variable scope

Implemented:

```
import time

class_stats = {
    "Warrior": (50, 7, 95),
    "Hunter" : (40, 10, 85),
    "Wizard" : (35, 12, 80),
}

class ClassBase:
    def __init__(self, class_name, health, damage, hit_chance):
        self.class_name = class_name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.hit_chance = hit_chance

def get_choice(question, choices):
    print(question)
    letter_choice_dict = {}
    for i, choice in enumerate(choices):
        letter_choice_dict[chr(ord("A") + i)] = choice
    for letter, choice in letter_choice_dict.items():
        print(letter + ") " + choice)
    user_choice = input().upper()

    try:
        return letter_choice_dict[user_choice]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid choice " + user_choice)

def main():
    print("Welcome to Blades of Goblonia!")

    user_name = input("What is your name?")
    print("Hello, " + user_name + "!")
    chosen_class = get_choice("What class would you like to be?", class_stats.keys())

    stats = class_stats[chosen_class]
    user = ClassBase(chosen_class, *stats)
    print("You are a " + user.class_name + "!")

    enemy = ClassBase("Goblin", 30, 10, 60)
    print("Out of nowhere, a", enemy.class_name, "appears!")

    time.sleep(1)

    action_chosen = get_choice("Would you like to", ["Hit", "Run", "Heal"])

    # do something with user and/or enemy depending on action_chosen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach should be more that of a class hierarchy, where each category of characters in your game is represented:

For instance, a `Character` could represent a generic character, a `Warrior` be a `Character` that kills enemies, and a `Magician`, be a `Character` that casts spells...

The code does not need to be repeated in each class, the attributes of a `Character` are accessible from its subclasses `Warrior` and `Magician`; Each subclass can have its own attributes, and its specific capabilities (different actions)

Maybe something like this:

```
class Character:

    def __init__(self, name, health=10, damage=0, hit_chance=.2, life_status=True):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.total_health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.hit_chance = hit_chance
        self.life_status = life_status
        print('Out of nowhere, a ' + self.__class__.__name__ + ' named ' + self.name + " appears!")

    def action(self):
        return "does nothing"

    def meet_somebody(self):
        return self.name + " says hello," + ' and ' + self.action()


class Warrior(Character):
    def action(self):    
        return "kills enemy"


class Magician(Character):
    def action(self):    
        return "casts a spell"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fred = Warrior('Fred')
    jack = Magician('Jack')

    print(fred.meet_somebody())
    print(jack.meet_somebody())
```

---

```
Out of nowhere, a Warrior named Fred appears!
Out of nowhere, a Magician named Jack appears!
Fred says hello, and kills enemy
Jack says hello, and casts a spell
```